# Express router ordering for params in beginning of url path

Tags: node.js, express

I am using express and I want to have my user profile URLs like this: example.com/:username

However, I still need other URLs such as example.com/login and example.com/view/:id

If I order the router like this, it treats "login" as a username when a request is sent to example.com/login:

```
router.get('/:username', function (req, res, next) {
  res.render('profile', {data: req.params.username});
})

router.get('/login', function (req, res, next) {
  res.render('login', {data: null});
})

router.get('/view/:id', function (req, res, next) {
  res.render('view', {data: req.params.id});
})
```

If I put the /:username router at the end, everything works correctly.  However, if someone went to example.com/view (without an id), I need it to send an error that the view controller didn't receive an id.  Instead, it sees it as a username again and instead sends an error that the username doesn't exist.

What is the cleanest way to solve this? Do I just have to add a router for all base url paths?  (Something like this):

```
router.get('/login', function (req, res, next) {
  res.render('login', {data: null});
})

router.get('/view/:id', function (req, res, next) {
  res.render('view', {data: req.params.id});
})

router.get('/view', function (req, res, next) {
  res.render('viewError', {data: null});
})

router.get('/:username', function (req, res, next) {
  res.render('profile', {data: req.params.username});
})
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not entirely sure if this is the right way to do it, but then again this sounds like something I might encounter and I would like it to be solved by this method until I find a better solution.

The below solution uses a single route for the path format `/:value`, be it login, view or any username, hence you could put in a simple if-else-if or switch to give control to respective controllers or just simply render a view from it. This way the order in which it has to be handled doesn't matter at all.

```
router.get("/:username", function(req, res, next) {
  if (req.params.username === "login") {
    res.render("login", { data: null });
  } else if (req.params.username === "view") {
    res.render("viewError", { data: null });
  } else {
    res.render("profile", { data: req.params.username });
  }
});

router.get("/view/:id", function(req, res, next) {
  res.render("view", { data: req.params.id });
});
```